# Stack with id X does not exist or has been deleted - cfn-init

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a CloudFormation Stack but getting:

> Stack with id airflow-layer does not exist or has been deleted

The airflow-layer is the name of the cloud formation stack that I am creating. What is the correct way to auto reference the stack that I am creating?

```
{
    "Description": "AWS CloudFormation to airflow",
    "Resources": {
        "AirflowEC2": {
            "Metadata": {
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
                    "configSets": {
                        "install_airflow": [
                            "install_airflow"
                        ]
                    },
                    "install_airflow": {
                        "commands": {
                            "test": {
                                "command": "echo Ola mundo"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "Properties": {
                "ImageId": "ami-9abea4fb",
                "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
                "KeyName": "CLOUD_ADMIN",
                "SecurityGroupIds": [
                    "sg-03851765"
                ],
                "SubnetId": "subnet-0820796d",
                "Tags": [
                    {
                        "Key": "Name",
                        "Value": "ec2-airflow-production"
                    }
                ],
                "UserData": {
                    "Fn::Base64": {
                        "Fn::Join": [
                            "",
                            [
                                "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
                                "sudo apt-get update\n",
                                "sudo apt-get -y install python-setuptools\n",
                                "sudo apt-get -y install python-pip\n",
                                "sudo pip install https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest.tar.gz\n",
                                "cfn-init -s '",
                                {
                                    "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
                                },
                                "' -r AirflowEC2 -c install_airflow"
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance"
        },
        "AirflowElasticIP": {
            "Properties": {
                "AllocationId": "eipalloc-7214ae17",
                "InstanceId": {
                    "Ref": "AirflowEC2"
                }
            },
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In which region are you trying to create the stack?

Answer (score 5):

I got this error when I ran "cfn-init" without a "--region". Including it fixes the problem.